# nginx 1.10.2 on RHEL6 - having problems with accepting slash in URL

Tags: nginx, slash-arguments

My nginx server won't accept these kind of URL's, while apache handles them just fine:

http://domain/file.php/?variablename=variable

nginx accept only that:

http://domain/file.php?variablename=variable

Please let me know if the first approach is "doable" for nginx.
Thanks

Comment: The `/` following the `.php` is called *path info*. You will need a configuration that processes path info correctly. See [this link](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/phpfcgi/).

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution myself, so if someone struggles with that API calls, just instert that in the config:

```
location ~ .php/ { 

    rewrite ^(.*.php)/ $1 last;

}
```